# Replacing keys (enclosed by brackets) in a string by value based on key–value pair map

Tags: javascript

say the following code:

```
var s = 'Hey, {{name}} {{lastname}}! Your age is {{age}}.';
```

after calling

```
s.apply({name: "Alex", lastname: "Cole", age: 20})
```

I would expect the string to be

```
var s = 'Hey, Alex Cole! Your age is 20.';
```

Comment: Why exactly would you expect that?

Comment: @Pointy that's expected from the code we're supposed to write.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace by searching for the pattern with curly brackets.

```js
const
    apply = (s, o) => s.replace(/\{\{([^}]+)\}\}/g, (_, k) => o[k]),
    string = 'Hey, {{name}} {{lastname}}! Your age is {{age}}.';

console.log(apply(string, { name: "Alex", lastname: "Cole", age: 20 }));
```

Answer (score 0):

what you want is:

```js
var s = `Hey, ${name} ${lastname}! Your age is ${age}.`;
```

this is considering you have already destructured the object

```js
const {name, lastname, age} = object;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at this syntax:

```
const data = {
  name:'Alex',
  lastname:'Cole',
  age:20,
};

const s = `Hey, ${data.name} ${data.lastname}! Your age is ${data.age}`;
```